# Creating Result Sources by PowerShell

Tags: search, powershell, result-source

I want to create a PowerShell script that creates Result Sources in Search Service Application.

If it's possible I would like to state the Result Sources in an XML-file with a `sourceID`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below `server side Powershell` function to create a `Result Source`. I have used it in `SharePoint 2013 On Premise`

```
function CreateResultSource(){
[CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$siteUrl,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$searchServiceName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$query,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$resultSourceName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][boolean]$setAsDefault,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][boolean]$setPeopleType
    )

try{

        # Get Site, SSA and owner
        #
        $site = get-spsite $siteUrl -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
        $sspApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication $searchServiceName
        $fedManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Query.FederationManager($sspApp)
        $searchOwner = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchObjectOwner([Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchObjectLevel]::SPSite, $site.RootWeb)

        # Query properties
        #
        $queryProperties = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Rules.QueryTransformProperties

        # Check if source exists
        #
        $source = $fedManager.GetSourceByName($resultSourceName, $searchOwner)
        if ($source -eq $null)
        {
            # create result source
            #
            $resultSource = $fedManager.CreateSource($searchOwner)
            $resultSource.Name = $resultSourceName

            if ($setPeopleType)
            {
                $resultSource.ProviderId =  $fedManager.ListProviders()['Local People Provider'].Id
                Write-host  $resultSourceName "set as default 'People Search Results'" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            }
            else{
                $resultSource.ProviderId = $fedManager.ListProviders()['Local SharePoint Provider'].Id
            }

            $resultSource.CreateQueryTransform($queryProperties, $query)
            $resultSource.Commit()

            if ($setAsDefault)
            {
                try{
                    $fedManager.UpdateDefaultSource($resultSource.Id, $searchOwner)
                    Write-host  $resultSourceName "set as default result source" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                }
                catch {
                    Write-Host "Error : fail to set as default " $resultSourceName " :  " $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
                }
            }
            Write-host "Created successfully" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        else
        {
            write-host "Result Source exists!" -ForegroundColor Yellow

        }
    }
    catch{
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
CreateResultSource "http://YourSite.com" "Search Service App Name" "Your KQL Query" "Your Result Source Name"  $False $False
```